# Nested Scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

How can we give priority in nested scrolling? Imagine we have a `ListView` which consists of big rows that needs scrolling as well. now we want to let `ListView` scrolls when the inner layout scrolling is done.

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

      <ScrollView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/poicroll"
    >

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/addLay"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="490dp"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:paddingRight="5dp"
           android:paddingTop="10dp" >


//Your Data/ Content here





 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSavePOI"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content >


//Your Listview here


    </HorizontalScrollView>

         </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this hope it will help you

Comment: Thx dude but I'm afraid we didn't get each other :D I know how to implement scrolling , just wanna know how to give focus to the rows of a listView and then to the listView itself